# Run an Azure Databricks notebook from another notebook with ipywidget

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, ipywidgets

I am trying to run a notebook from another notebook using the  dbutils.notebook.run as follows:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
from ipywidgets import Box

button = widgets.Button(description='Run model')
out = widgets.Output()
def on_button_clicked(b):
    button.description = 'Run model'
    with out:
        dbutils.notebook.run("/mynotebookpath",60)

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
widgets.VBox([button, out])
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> IllegalArgumentException: Context not valid. If you are calling this
> outside the main thread, you must set the Notebook context via
> dbutils.notebook.setContext(ctx), where ctx is a value retrieved from
> the main thread (and the same cell)

I can run the notebook just fine when I do `%run` on a single cell and even `dbutils.notebook.run("/mynotebook", 60)` on a single cell. However I cannot get it to run within the ipywidget context

Comment: can you specify which databricks are you using azure,aws or community edition?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula  Its Azure

Answer (score 1):

When I executed the given code, I have got the same error. However, there is no way to follow the error message to use `dbutils.notebook.setContext` as there is no setContext attribute.

[image]

- Using `dbutils.notebook.run` also creates an untitled job run. So, as an alternative you can use `Jobs 2.0` to run the notebook.
- The following is the code that you can use:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import requests

response = None

def my_function(param):
    print(f"This is {param}")
    global response

    my_json = {"notebook_task": {"notebook_path": "/nb2"},"run_name": "execute notebook","timeout_seconds": 3600,"existing_cluster_id": "<cluster_id>"}   
    auth = {"Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>"}
    response = requests.post('https://<workspace_instance>/api/2.0/jobs/runs/submit', json = my_json, headers=auth).json()
    print(response)

button = widgets.Button(description="Run Model")
output = widgets.Output()

display(button, output)

def on_button_click(b):
    with output:
        print("button is clicked")
        my_function('in fuction')

button.on_click(on_button_click)
```

[image]

- You can monitor this run and check for its execution. The following is the sample run of my notebook.

[image]

Comment: Amazing @Saideep, that worked perfectly. I do however need to pass a partameter but dont know what the equivalent would be in jason: e.g dbutils.notebook.run("notebook_path", 60, {"file_input": file})

Comment: Unfortunately, `runs/submit` does not support passing notebook parameters. Another alternative is to create a job with task to run required notebook. You can use code similar to [this image](https://i.imgur.com/whrE4NA.png) where job_id is the id of the single task job that you have created to run required notebook. You can access these parameters using widgets. [This image](https://i.imgur.com/qpsTCrd.png) is a sample output run for the same.